# Published app not visible in Google Play

Tags: android, visible, google-play

I published one app to Android Market which is like a call denying and messaging app. I am fetching user contacts from the device and store this in my database. Because of this my app got denied and I could not able to see the app in market.

I got the mail from Google developer support that saying this violation issues. What should I do to overcome this? How to publish an app which has the feature of reading user contacts.

Comment: its better to remove your violations otherwise if you upload it again your account will be suspended, one of my account was suspended due to this reason

Answer (score 0):

The links for Apps in the Playstore are always built with the same pattern, it looks like this:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME

so you can use that link to see if your App is published or not, just replace YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME with the actual name of the package like com.google.android.music

Comment: tried this.It not working.Google saying no such file

Answer (score 0):

Are you fetching contacts directly without informing to user?fetch the contacts which are required & with permission of user

Answer (score 0):

After One Day you have wait to make synchronization of your app with Google so please wait one day it make verification of app For Google To customer interaction

1:- it make user intersection make easy  what kind of app you have upload
2:- You will get more benefits with This strategy in feature because of Verification of app

Comment: if You have upload that app before some days then you have package name that you Paste in Google play search bar and search that  then you can find that app

Comment: read the problem again. " Because of this my app got denied and I could able to see the app in market . I got the mail from Google developer support that saying this violation issues ."

Comment: Google make first Time Verification Of App and user that's by Google get Time of Looking of App in to Play store Account